# 2D PCA on 3D data

Tags: r, plot, pca

Given that my input 3D data is in a file "myFile.txt", organized as

```
435 43 23
234 23 453
212 45 2345
...
```

I want to perform PCA on it, and extract only the first
two principal components. What would be the easiest way
to achieve this? I have R and mdp on disposal, but I'm not
sure about the set of commands I need to execute 
to make any of these useful.

I would appreciate constructive comments instead of ignorant
downvote. The purpose is to help me find the solution, after all...

Comment: Here's my constructive comment: "shows little research effort" is one of the official reasons for downvoting. In this case, any simple Google search would have revealed what commands to investigate, and then you could have looked up the examples as Gavin has demonstrated. At that point, I'd be more than happy to assist with whatever problems you encounter in writing your own code. But there is no evidence of that in your question: instead you ask us to do it for you, hence my downvote.

Comment: I generally agree, but I've definitely done some research. However, I did not write where I was stuck, as I hoped that one implementation might be favored over another. The part after "Extract components 1 and 2" in the answer below was what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R the recommended function is `prcomp()`. Read its help file `?prcomp`.

An example is:

```
mod <- prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE)
```

`mod` is then an object of class `"prcomp"` and the matrix of eigenvectors (the principal components, raw/unscaled) is in component `x`

```
> str(mod)
List of 5
 $ sdev    : num [1:4] 1.575 0.995 0.597 0.416
 $ rotation: num [1:4, 1:4] -0.536 -0.583 -0.278 -0.543 0.418 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4"
 $ center  : Named num [1:4] 7.79 170.76 65.54 21.23
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ scale   : Named num [1:4] 4.36 83.34 14.47 9.37
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Murder" "Assault" "UrbanPop" "Rape"
 $ x       : num [1:50, 1:4] -0.976 -1.931 -1.745 0.14 -2.499 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:50] "Alabama" "Alaska" "Arizona" "Arkansas" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "prcomp"
```

Look at the `x` component:

```
> head(mod$x)
                  PC1        PC2         PC3          PC4
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297  1.08400162  0.001450164
```

Extract components 1 and 2

```
> scrs <- mod$x[, 1:2]
> head(scrs)
                  PC1        PC2
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297
```

Then you can plot them etc:

```
plot(scrs, asp = 1) ## asp = 1 gives equal scaling to x and y axes
```